# In R, how can I find all objects in a vector that are also in a txt file?

Tags: r, vector

I'm working on the infinite monkey problem, where a 'monkey' types 5 letter words (so these are randomly generated 5 character sequences in a vector). And I have to compare these 5 letter word jumbos to a large .txt file containing 5500+ English 5 letter words. To sort of map how many real words can be generated randomly this way.

What function can I use to see which objects are the same in the .txt file and the vector which contains the monkey's randomly generated 'words'?

I don't know if it is easier to compare the vector directly to the .txt file or if I should make the .txt file into a vector, so i appreciate any tips!

Comment: You would want to start with reading in the text file into memory. then splitting each word into a vector. The word matching is straighforward with `%in%`.

Comment: With 5500+ words you might want to sort them and use a binary search, especially if you have a large number of monkey "words" to look up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
which_right = text_file[monkey_words %in% text_file]
```

where text_file is your original words in english, and monkey_words the monkey typing, both character vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Due to I don't have your word list I tried to use most common 1000 English word from open [list](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/deekayen/4148741/raw/01c6252ccc5b5fb307c1bb899c95989a8a284616/1-1000.txt). I used this list in the code below, you can directly use it.

Let's say you assigned what monkey typed into `single_word_of_monkey` variable.
You can check it whether in the wordlist with code below:

```
#I am fetching the word list from web
url_wordlist="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/deekayen/4148741/raw/01c6252ccc5b5fb307c1bb899c95989a8a284616/1-1000.txt"
wordlist <- read.csv(url_wordlist,header=FALSE)
#lets see the words
print(head(wordlist,3))

single_word_of_monkey="the"
#to find whether word is in the wordlist
subset(wordlist,V1==single_word_of_monkey)
```

It will return the `the` value because it is in the wordlist. If the unmeaning word like `thex` becomes subject code will throw nothing.